# why I am getting this error even though I have installed openai?

Tags: python, openai-api

[image: Using vscode and already installed openai but still getting this errors]

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it but still getting this errors

Comment: Please share your code and FULL error message as text in this question. You can copy/paste and then highlight what you pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor for the quote and `"` button in the editor for the error message to preserve whitespace. More importantly, you cut off the error message; the important part of the error is at the bottom. .

Comment: and you've omitted the end quote in line 4, probably the openai error is just a sideffect of that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this code with cmd sometimes it happens code doesn't work on vs but work fine when run on cmd and also put " on line 4 after key[image]